# Telerik Ajax CheckBox not displaying in MVC3 Telerik Grid

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using telerik grid in which i am adding a check box with a column bound value.

my problem is when i am using Client Template like :

```
columns.Bound(o => o.CaseID).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' value='<#= CaseID #>' />")
```

.Width(5)
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });

In this Check box is not getting appear but value of CaseID is getting display.

when i am using like Column.Bound like :

```
columns.Bound(c => c.CaseID).Title("").Format("<input type='checkbox' value='<#= CaseID #>' />").Encoded(false).Width(5);
```

check box is getting display but value of CaseID is not getting Bind with Check Box.

I am using MVC3 with aspx engine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I googled all the telerik site but i was not able to find it any how, finally i maked it work from my self to make some extra changes like :

```
columns.Bound(c => c.CaseID).Title("").Format("<input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' value='{0}'  id ='{0}'/>").Encoded(false).Width(5);
```

we have to pass value like this when we are using telerik AJAX check box in telerik grid.