# using checkbox in telerik grid

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm using checkbox in Telerik Grid.
following is my code

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<ProductModel>(Model.Products.Data)
                    .Name("products-grid")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
                        .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' value='<#= Id #>' />")
                        .Title("")
                        .Width(36)
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });

                        columns.Bound(x => x.Id);
                        columns.Bound(x => x.Name);
                        columns.Bound(x => x.Published)
                            .Width(100)
                            .Template(x => x.Published.ToString().ToLower())
                            .Centered();

                    })
                    .Pageable(settings => settings.Total(Model.Products.Total).PageSize(gridPageSize).Position(GridPagerPosition.Both))
                    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("ProductReport", "Product"))
                    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("onDataBinding"))
                    .EnableCustomBinding(true)
                    )
```

I just see Id's in the checkbox column instead of checkboxes. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code ??

i checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426240/telerik-ajax-checkbox-not-displaying-in-mvc3-telerik-grid) and a few other but they dint answer my problem..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your code definition, you just defined template in ajax call mode (with clientTemplate method):

```
.ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' value='<#= Id #>' />")
```

But you should define the server-side template too, this template is used at your first and direct request:

```
.Template(@<text><input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' value='@Item.Id' /></text>)
```

Comment: yes, exactly! one for server-side rendering and another for client-side rendering.(where grid ajax calls just return JSON data).

Comment: nop.. the checkboxes dint appear.. i used a link instead of checkbox to solve my problem.. @Mahmoud Moravej